# Text ellipsis in a flex column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get text ellipsis working in a flex column layout, within a flex row. A use case would be for something like tabs with icons - all the tabs need to fit within a row, and potentially be truncated, and the tabs have an internal column layout so the icon goes above the text.

It is possible to get the sizing to work correctly, but I can't work out a way to get truncation to work while maintaining horizontal flexibility.

I've created [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/wsYhKPgn4razvcy35Iwq?p=preview) to demonstrate - as you can see in both options the stretch is working correctly and the row-wrappers / column-wrappers are shrunk to fit the container, but the text ellipsis stops working as soon as you switch the wrapper to a column.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
<style>
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.column-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
}

.row-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
}

.ellipsis {
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap
}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column-wrapper">
    <p class="ellipsis">This is some very long text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-wrapper">
    <p class="ellipsis">This is some very long text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row-wrapper">
    <p class="ellipsis">This is some very long text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row-wrapper">
    <p class="ellipsis">This is some very long text</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The desired result is that the internal column truncates in the same way as the internal row. Obviously it still needs to be a column to support icons etc.

FYI this is the underlying issue for https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16532

FYI2 it is possible to get this working using display: block instead of display:flex for the column wrappers, but that won't support other required use cases for these containers.

Comment: @LGSon I've updated the question with a verifiable sample.

Comment: Perfect, upvoted and retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `align-items: center` from your `column-wrapper` and center the items in another way possibly. Or if the resualt from the first example  is what you want then just remove the `align-items: center` and it should be good

```css
/* Styles go here */
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.column-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
}

.row-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
}

.ellipsis {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>Internal row</h2>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="row-wrapper">
        <p class="ellipsis">This is some very long text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row-wrapper">
        <p class="ellipsis">This is some very long text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row-wrapper">
        <p class="ellipsis">This is some very long text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <h2>Internal column</h2>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="column-wrapper">
        <p class="ellipsis">This is some very long text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column-wrapper">
        <p class="ellipsis">This is some very long text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column-wrapper">
        <p class="ellipsis">This is some very long text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```